# How to group results by hour, which includes hours with no record

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table which contains all orders, i'm trying to separate orders by hour.
if there is no record for an specific hour, the query will ignore that hour, but what i'm trying to achieve is to report'0' for that hour.

I also joined the table with a temporary table containing all hours.

```
SELECT sum(orders.price), hour(orders.time) as hour
FROM orders 
RIGHT JOIN dummy_time as dummy
ON hour(orders.time) = dummy.time
WHERE state = 1
AND (date(orders.time) = '2014-06-17' or orders.time is null)
GROUP BY hour
```

You can view my query in [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67f79/7)

Comment: So if there were zero active orders in hour 1 you want a row of: `SUM(ORDERS.PRICE)`: `0` | `HOUR` : `1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all rows from `dummy_time`, move your conditions from your `WHERE` to your `RIGHT JOIN`. Also, select the hour from dummy.time so you will get all hours.

Use `COALESCE` to get values of `0` where an order doesn't have records.

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(orders.price),0), dummy.time as hour
FROM orders 
RIGHT JOIN dummy_time as dummy
ON hour(orders.time) = dummy.time
AND orders.state = 1
AND orders.time BETWEEN '2014-06-17 00:00:00' AND '2014-06-17 23:59:59'
GROUP BY dummy.time
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7adb/2

The query plan for the query below looks worse than the one above but because you reported that the `JOIN` seems to be the main source of slowness it's worth a try. The query below reduces the set of rows before doing a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(t1.orders_sum,0),
  t2.time
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    sum(orders.price) orders_sum, 
    hour(orders.time) orders_hour
  FROM orders 
  WHERE orders.state = 1
  AND orders.time BETWEEN '2014-06-17 00:00:00' AND '2014-06-17 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY hour(orders.time)
) t1 RIGHT JOIN dummy_time t2 ON t1.orders_hour = t2.time
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0775b/1

Also, make sure your tables are indexed

```
CREATE INDEX test_index1 ON orders (state,time);
CREATE INDEX test_index2 ON dummy_time (time);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but its still to slow, without `JOIN` it takes 0.04 secs to finish, but with `JOIN` it takes 6 seconds, is there anyway to speed this up ?

Comment: @Nevercom see update, also is it possible that the query w/o `JOIN` is cached?

Comment: @Nevercom also updated 1st query to group by `dummy.time` instead of `hour(orders.time)`

Comment: Whats the difference between this 2 queries ? I noticed both use `RIGHT JOIN`, but why second query is so faster ? (I wanna understand `SQL` better)

Comment: @Nevercom the 2nd query does the `RIGHT JOIN` after the `GROUP BY`, so it will only join a maximum of 24 rows (1 for each hour). The first query does the join before the `GROUP BY` so it will join every row in the `orders` table.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67f79/20) what you are looking for? It uses a case for when state=1 versus state=0 on whether to display sum orders or whether to display 0. If not please let me know your desired result.

Comment: Actually, I've used `CASE`, but it was very slow compared to filtering results with `state=1`

Comment: So you want the results of using case but the speed of using state?

Comment: Yes, it took 7 second using `CASE` which is really long time